# NuxtJS FATAL Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation

Tags: nuxt.js

Hello so I got an error while running `nuxt generate`

```
 ERROR  Could not resolve routes                                                                                                                                                                                                14:57:20


 FATAL  Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation                                                                                                                                                                   14:57:20

  ---
  ^
```

This is the source that caused the problem:
nuxt.config.js

```
  generate: {
    routes: function () {
      const fs = require('fs')
      const path = require('path')
      return fs.readdirSync('./assets/content/blog').map(file => {
        return {
          route: `/blog/${path.parse(file).name}`, // Return the slug
          payload: require(`./assets/content/blog/${file}`)
        }
      })
    }
  },
```

Comment: have you tried to replace your const by `import * as path from 'path'; import * as sf from 'sf'` 
or moving them at the beginning of the file (outside the object) ?

Comment: That snippet code is in the nuxt.config.js file

Comment: ok.. so did you try?

Comment: that didn't work